# Python reading csv file with semicolon delimiter: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read a csv file exported from Microsoft Excel, looking like this:

```
114.9;280.9;501.5;0;W10;Firewall south;A;1;2;;
119.0;280.9;501.5;0;W10;Southern escape route;B;2;3;asdasdf;
120.5;280.0;501.5;0;W10;Southern escape route;C;3;4;;
```

The delimiter is semicolon and some of the columns might be empty. For example column 10 may be populated with `asdasdf` as an example. My code looks like this:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(inFile), delimiter=";")

nodesTable = window.getNodesTable()
pathsTable = window.getPathsTable()
clearTable(nodesTable)
clearTable(pathsTable)

for x, y, z, safe, mod, descr_node, name, start, end, descr_path in reader:
    nodesTable.SetStringItem(counter, nodesTable_ID_x, x)
    nodesTable.SetStringItem(counter, nodesTable_ID_y, y)
    nodesTable.SetStringItem(counter, nodesTable_ID_z, z)
    nodesTable.SetStringItem(counter, nodesTable_ID_SafeArea, safe)
    nodesTable.SetStringItem(counter, nodesTable_ID_Module, mod)
    nodesTable.SetStringItem(counter, nodesTable_ID_Description, descr_node)

    pathsTable.SetStringItem(counter, pathsTable_ID_Name, name)
    pathsTable.SetStringItem(counter, pathsTable_ID_StartNode, start)
    pathsTable.SetStringItem(counter, pathsTable_ID_EndNode, end)
    pathsTable.SetStringItem(counter, pathsTable_ID_Description, descr_path)
```

I am getting the error `ValueError: too many values to unpack`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It sounds like there is at least one row that does not contain all of the values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are **10** semicolons in each line of your CSV file, which means, that the line will be splitted into **11** elements. In your `for` loop, there are only **10** variables used. Change the line into:

```
for x, y, z, safe, mod, descr_node, name, start, end, descr_path, _ in reader:
```

and ignore the `_` variable, which will get the empty character between the last `;` in the line and the end of line.

Or change your whole loop into:

```
cols = (nodesTable_ID_x, nodesTable_ID_y, nodesTable_ID_z,
        nodesTable_ID_SafeArea, nodesTable_ID_Module,
        nodesTable_ID_Description, pathsTable_ID_Name,
        pathsTable_ID_StartNode, pathsTable_ID_EndNode,
        pathsTable_ID_Description)

for rec in reader:
    for col, val in zip(cols, rec):
        nodesTable.SetStringItem(counter, col, val)
```